# Scale text on change relative to container in React

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

I'm using React.js and I want input text to fit it's container but onChange.

For example: if a user enter 'T'

[image]

and then he enters 'E', so the input now is 'TE'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created one small application demoing this. I am using a couple of state `text` which manages the current text in a textbox and a `fontSize` which is used to calculate the current font size for text. I have kept an upper size of 200px and a lower size of 50px so, that text doesn't look too large or small. The ratio is `1.2` which means whenever some add a new character text size will increase to 1.2 and if a character is removed then the size would reduce by 1.2. Here is an application.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [fontSize, setFontSize] = useState(200);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const updateFontSize = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      if (text.length > value.length) {
        const textSize = Math.ceil(fontSize * 1.5, 10);
        fontSize < 200 && setFontSize(textSize);
      } else if (text.length < value.length) {
        const textSize = Math.ceil(fontSize / 1.5, 10);
        fontSize > 50 && setFontSize(textSize);
      }
      setText(value);
    },
    [fontSize, text]
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(event) => updateFontSize(event.target.value)}
      />
      <div style={{ fontSize: `${fontSize}px` }}>{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-grass-472o3?file=/src/App.js) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

The [react-scale-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scale-text) module should also do what's needed.